# Как сделать затемнение блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, есть блоки, и как по очереди их затемнять, дело в том что они стоят в притык и ховером у меня не получается сделать, может кто поможет[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выложите ваш код, где не получается?

Comment: https://codepen.io/_Vlasok_/pen/pogwoPz

Comment: что значит по очереди Затемнять, логику объясните.

Comment: При наведении на блок, он не затемняется, а все остальные затемняются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
 .elem {
   color: red;
   background: yellow;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   border: 1px solid #000;
 }
 .items:hover .elem:not(:hover) {
   background: green;
   color: #FFF;
 }
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <li class="elem">1</li>
  <li class="elem">2</li>
  <li class="elem">3</li>
  <li class="elem">4</li>
</div>
```

Используйте :not(:hover)
Логика такая - слушаем весь список и применяем стили только к тем элементам, которые не имеют :hover

Answer (score 0):

Сделал, используя .class:not(:hover)